# Fourier transforms via Kurzweil-Henstock integral on locally compact commutative groups

Tags: lie-groups, fourier-analysis, integration, topological-groups

Is it possible to define Fourier transforms on locally compact commutative groups using the Kurzweil-Henstock integral instead of the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=yLJ&rls=en&ei=zzCnS5O1G4mXtgfm7rWnCg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAUQBSgA&q=Kurzweil-Henstock+haar+measure&spell=1

Comment: Do none of those articles answer your question?

Comment: The question is essentially, can you use the Haar measure with the K-H integral.  My guess is that it is not possible.  The whole beauty of the Lebesgue integral is that it can be defined with respect to an arbitrary measure.

Comment: It's remarkable how quickly this question went to the top of the results for that search (at least on my computer).

Comment: Most of the Tulone and Skvortsov stuff seems to be for zero-dimensional LC groups.

Comment: Sloppy guesswork: it seems to me that a KH function multiplied by a cts character ought to be KH, and so it also has a KH integral; so, are we asked whether the full family of these has enough of the dualizing properties we expect of a fourier transform in the Lebesgue integral sense?

Comment: it can be done .see treatise of henstock

Comment: @AnilP Link? At the very least give a proper reference...